# Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Only one element on document allowed

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm trying to load an external svg file and then write additional SVG elements on top of it. When I do, I get the following  error

> Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Only one element on document allowed

when I inspect within Chrome.

Here's the HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <title>Hello World</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="mySvg">
        <circle cx="40" cy="30" r="15" fill="#FF00FF"
          stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" />
      </svg>
      <object data="img/drawing.svg" type="image/svg+xml"
        align="center" id="svgDrw" height="80vh"></object>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/problem.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's problem.js:

```
var svgXtraDoc;
var d = document.getElementById("svgDrw");

d.addEventListener("load",function(){

  // get the inner DOM 
  svgXtraDoc = d.contentDocument;
  // get the inner element by id
  svgRect1 = svgXtraDoc.getElementById("MyRect1");
  svgRect2 = svgXtraDoc.getElementById("MyRect2");
}, false);


function addRect() {
  var svgRect = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 
    "rect");
  svgRect.setAttribute("x", 100);
  svgRect.setAttribute("y", 100);
  svgRect.setAttribute("width", 100);
  svgRect.setAttribute("height", 100);
  svgRect.style.fill = "red";
  // mySvg.appendChild(svgRect);
  svgXtraDoc.appendChild(svgRect);
}

document.getElementById("mySvg").addEventListener("click", addRect);
```

... and here's drawing.svg, stripped of some of the Inkscapy cruft:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   width="29.02857mm"
   height="37.092064mm"
   viewBox="0 0 102.85714 131.42857"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1">
  <g
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(-205.71428,-218.07649)">
    <rect
       style="stroke:none;fill-opacity:1;fill:#5eb056"
       id="MyRect1"
       width="102.85714"
       height="131.42857"
       x="205.71428"
       y="218.07649" />
    <rect
       style="fill:#000000;stroke:none;fill-opacity:1"
       id="MyRect2"
       width="42.857143"
       height="65.714287"
       x="231.42857"
       y="252.3622" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

The error arises when you click on the circle: the rectangle that should appear within the two-rectangle imported drawing doesn't appear, and the error message "Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Only one element on document allowed." is displayed in the console.

If I change this so the rectangle is added to the svg containing the circle, i.e. by uncommenting the line "// mySvg.appendChild(svgRect);", then the rectangle successfully appears.

I also know that the drawing file is successfully loading, because in other code (not included here for brevity reasons) I can change the colors of the rectangles within that file. So it seems that I can access existing elements within the file but not add elements.

Is there something about externally loaded SVGs versus inline SVGs that I'm not taking into account?

One last thing -- this is going into a Cordova app so I'd like to keep it small, so pure JavaScript solutions are preferred. I'll use JQuery or SnapSVG if I have to but it seems my needs are sufficiently simple that it should be possible to do this without external libraries.

Comment: I just worked out a way around my problem -- I want to add circles indicating event locations, so I can just put them in the original file with stroke and fill set to none and then make them visible at the appropriate time, rather than actually creating and adding them when the event happens. I'd still be interested in an answer to the question as asked though.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is a difference between the root node of a document and the document element.  What you want is the `<svg>` document element, but `.contentDocument` gets you the root node.

The root node is one hierarchy level further up.  This means, the `<svg>` document element resides inside the root node, and the root node may only have this one `<svg>` child element.

To get the document element, do this:

```
svgXtraDoc = d.contentDocument.documentElement;
```

Answer (score 190):

In my case, the DOM was complaining because I was trying to add a child in the **document itself**:

```
document.appendChild(myElement);
```

I solved it by getting a reference to the body tag:

```
document.body.appendChild(logger);
```

Comment: exactly,  because document can only  have a <html> element and nothing else. all other elements are child of  <html> element